# Rails: how to change a marker and add infowindow in Gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails, gmaps4rails2

I'm using the `Gmaps4rails gem` and this is the setup I have:

```
def show
    @items = Item.find(params[:id])
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@items) do |item, marker|
      marker.lat item.latitude
      marker.lng item.longitude
      marker.picture({
                     :url => "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/arrow.png",
                     :width   => 32,
                     :height  => 32
                 })
    end
    append_cur_location
  end

def append_cur_location
    @hash << { :lat=>action[0], :lng=>action[1]}
end

def action
  @lat_lng = cookies[:lat_lng].split("|")
end
```

I'm getting the current location from the `action method` and the `item` location from the `item.latitude` and `item.longitude`.

views/items/show.html.erb

```
<div style='width: 800px;'>
  <div id="map" style='width: 800px; height: 400px;'></div>
</div>

<script>
    handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
    handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
        markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
        handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
        handler.fitMapToBounds();
    });
</script>
```

With the above setup I got the map to show the current location and the item location. Also, I was able to change the item location marker. 
But I cant figure out how to change the current location marker and add the info box to the item location. Any ideas how to implement these changes?

Comment: I given solution for infowindow. Let me know what you expecting about changing current location.

Comment: @krishnar the info window pops up when I click on the item marker.... thank you!!! I would also like to change the current marker.. how can I do that?

Comment: you mean you want to update current_location maker with new lat,lng?

Comment: I want to change the marker picture for the current location, like I already have done for the item location.

Comment: OK. you mean u want different picture for current location ?

Comment: Yes but for the current location... which is been called from the `action method`

Comment: i updated answer. check

Comment: You are welcome. You might have got how to add infowindow to your current location as well.?

Comment: One more thing... is there a template I can use in order to stack everything in place inside the partial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**INFOWINDOW**

you can use marker.infowindow

```
def show
  @items = Item.find(params[:id])
  @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@items) do |item, marker|
    marker.lat item.latitude
    marker.lng item.longitude
    marker.picture({
                   :url => "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/arrow.png",
                   :width   => 32,
                   :height  => 32
               })

    #INFOWINDOW
    # Use can use partial to render infowindow
    # marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => 'items/info_page')
    # or else
    marker.infowindow "ITEM HERE!!!!"

  end
  append_cur_location
end
```

**DIFFERENT IMAGE FOR CURRENT LOCATION**

```
def append_cur_location
  @hash << { 
  :lat=>action[0], 
  :lng=>action[1],
  :picture=> {
      :url=> "http://people.mozilla.com/~faaborg/files/shiretoko/firefoxIcon/firefox-32.png",
      :width=>  32,
      :height=> 32
    }
  }
end
```